# AngularJS populate textbox from array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, forms, binding, textbox

I am facing a problem with AngularJS. I have made an application where a user can 
select a value from a dropdown list. If the user presses the "add" button, then an array is created that holds all his selections. I want to populate a textbox with all these selections. I have tried ng-repeat but it creates multiple textbox with each array value. This is what I've made so far:

**Controller**

```
$scope.multiCompare= [];

// Create the function to push the data into the "multiCompare" array
$scope.newCompare = function () {

    $scope.multiCompare.push($scope.compareDate);


    $scope.multiComparedate = '';



};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="installation_year" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Period</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="compareDate" ng-options="res for res in compareDates " ng-disabled="disableFormInput()" ></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="newCompare()">Add</button>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Compare</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div ng-repeat="num in multiCompare" track by $index>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="$parent.multiCompare[$index]">
                        <div> {{num}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The first image shows the result I'm getting when adding 2013 and 2014 and the second shows what I would like it to return.

[image: This is the result I'm getting]

[image: This is what I want it to show]

Can someone help me through this?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you provide the compareDates & multiCompare array?

Answer (score 1):

For rendering your Compare field input, you can take use of [`ngList`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) directive. That will bind your comma(,) separated output directly to the input element.

**Change**

```
<label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Compare</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div ng-repeat="num in multiCompare" track by $index>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="$parent.multiCompare[$index]">
        <div> {{num}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TO**

```
<label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Compare</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="multiCompare" ng-list/>
</div>
```

This could help you, Thanks.

Comment: The multiCompare array is populated with the selected dropdown-Period value every time a user clicks the add button, and I want this array to be binded with a textbox, in a comma separated output. Unfortunately the code above does not work in my case...

Comment: what `multiCompare` array does contain? can you give me some sample..
i was thinking it contains `[2013,2014]`

Comment: @Olgapoliti if my answer does helpful then mark it as correct...I'll edit my answer..is it ok for you?

Comment: I gave it a +1, since it was helpful, but was not the answer that solves my problem.  Since I had a hard time finding the answer to this problem, I wouldn't want you to edit your answer. Besides, a +1 is always a reward...

Comment: @Olgapoliti i asked you for get me the sample array because i didn't aware of `multiCompare`, i was waiting for you response. but you didn't gave me. And you question is also not that much clear..not explaining the problem correctly. Ok Thanks for vote up. :)

Comment: In my first comment, I say that multicompare is populated with the selected dropdown-Period value every time a user clicks the add button, and since there is an image showing that it contains years, I believe you can conclude that multiCompare contains years. I can't see why you are so annoyed, since I even posted images of what I wanted the result to look like. I will erase my answer, since I don't care about getting any credit. I just wanted some help. Anyway, I will accept your answer as correct, since I am grateful that you helped me. I do not wish to continue this argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70247/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-olga-politi).

Comment: @Olgapoliti Hey i don't want any credit, and please don't accept my answer..and don't give me upvote..I'm here to help..not to take credit. I said what i thought

Comment: @Olgapoliti uncheck my answer otherwise i will delete my answer..Not here to take credit

Comment: @Olgapoliti thanx..but why you removed your answer..please undelete it and mark it as correct..so that it will help other people if they have same problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do what I wanted. I changed my html code to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Compare</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="num in multiCompare" track by $index>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="multiCompare" ng-list {{num}} ng-show="$last" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And it worked!
Your ng-list suggestion was really helpful! Thank you very much!